# How to reload only a captcha image and not the whole page

Tags: php, javascript

I need some help, as I can't reload a captcha image in my form, if the writing over the image is not very clear or simple to read, as it can happens sometimes.

I read a lot about that, here and around in the internet but my problem is different from what most people seem to have to face. In fact I create the captcha image in a page called - captcha.php - and then in another page called - contacts.php - I create the writing for the image and a casual unique string that I pass to the captcha.php file, as I don't want to use the sessions or cookies, but I use instead a database with a table called - validation.
Translating all this in PHP, the captcha.php has this code to retrieve the string:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  

try
    {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM validation WHERE url_key = ? AND expire_date > NOW()");

        $stmt->execute(array($_GET['token']));

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);          
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
        die(); 
    }       
etc.....
```

and then my contacts.php has this:

```
 $url_key = sha1(uniqid(rand(), true)); 

    $captcha = random_string(4);

    try
        {
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO validation (id_validation, url_key, captcha, expire_date) VALUES ('', ?, ?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE))");

            $stmt->execute(array($url_key, $captcha));
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
            die(); 
        }
```

Now I do need, of course, to refresh just my image and not the entire contacts.php page.
I know you can do that with Ajax, but I've got no good knowledge about that.

My contacts.php has the tag img to show the reader the captcha:

```
 <img src="captcha.php?token=<?php echo $url_key; ?>" alt="" />
```

I tried to change it this way:

```
  <img src="captcha.php?token=<?php echo $url_key; ?>" id="captcha" />
  <a href="#" onClick="return changeCaptcha('captcha')">Reload the image</a>
```

and then in my head section, I put this Javascript code:

```
  function changeCaptcha()
{
    document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'captcha.php' +
     Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
}
```

but it doesn't work at all.
If I click on the link the captcha disappears completely.

I tried then to change this:

```
   <img src="captcha.php?token=<?php echo $url_key; ?>" id="captcha" />
   <a href="#" onClick="return reloadImg('captcha');">Reload the image</a>
```

and then with a new Javascript file, that's:

```
  function reloadImg(id) {
   var obj = document.getElementById(id);
   var src = obj.src;
   var pos = src.indexOf('?');
   if (pos >= 0) {
   src = src.substr(0, pos);
  }  
  var date = new Date();
  obj.src = src + '?v=' + date.getTime();
  return false;
}
```

but it doesn't work even this way. The problem is in the - php echo $url_key;  - as I don't know how to treat this. I can't do this for example:

```
  function changeCaptcha()
   {
    document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'captcha.php?token=<?php echo $url_key; ?>' +
    Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
}
```

as it's wrong again.

Do you have some ideas?
Thank you in advance.
Bye.

Comment: You are requesting captcha.php with a new and random `token`, while `token` should be available in the database. That doesn't work. This means you should handle this in `captcha.php`: if you get a new token that you've never seen before, `INSERT` that token into the database with a random 4 character string and create the image.

Comment: As a general rule always avoid `SELECT * FROM [Table]`. See http://www.bryantwebconsulting.com/blog/index.cfm/2006/4/17/avoid_select_

Comment: But I already do that in my contacts.php file, and I use the code above with $_GET in the captcha.php file just to communicate with the file mentioned above.